# Show when post edited in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits

When reading comments, it's often really *really* annoying that they refer to past revisions. This means the comments are sometimes are no longer relevant or sometimes just plain confusing.

My feature request is that in the comments, a notification is posted to show when in the comment queue the edit was made (along with the edit description (ommitted below)) and by whom, like so:

[image: Example]

I think something like this will greatly help the usefulness of comments on SO.

Comment: If you see comments that don't apply due to subsequent revisions, simply flag them as Obsolete.

Comment: You can look at the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732348/timeline), but only for questions.